# ASP.NET MVC show dialog with predefined data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

I tried to utilize the jquery.dialog but it seems not suiting my needs as i have the data already loaded in the view where i need to show up the details popup.

My current view looks like the following:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Records"] as List<wow.Models.DetailsView>)
{
  <div class="detail-container" id="dialog-opener" class="detail-item">
     <p>@item.Title</p>
  </div>
}
```

When i click the detail-container i would like to see the other details in an additional dialog/popup (embedded though). I tried jQuery but i was not sure where i should declare the dialog div.

Sorry if i missed to explain some details but please ask me and i will clarify ...

Thank you

P.S. the dialog would look like the following (containing the data contained in the VIewData):

```
<div "dialog">
    <p>@item.Title</p>
    <p>@item.Date</p>
    <p>@item.UserID</p>
    //etc.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2qh8wmnp/)**

```
$( ".detail-container" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      $(".ui-dialog-content").empty();
      $(".ui-dialog-content").append($(this).find('p').text());
});
```

> Tip: You are adding classes two times. Instead add it only once and
>   remove id from div as it will create duplicate ids which are against
>   the HTML rule.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Records"] as List<wow.Models.DetailsView>)
{
  <div class="detail-container detail-item">
     <p>@item.Title</p>
  </div>
}
```

**UPDATE**

To add extra data first need to put it somewhere in the `html`, and it will be better if appended as `data-*` html5 attribute as the one below:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Records"] as List<wow.Models.DetailsView>)
{
  <div class="detail-container" id="dialog-opener" data-date="@item.Date" data-uid="@item.UserID" class="detail-item">
     <p>@item.Title</p>
  </div>
}
```

Now you can retrieve it as below:

```
$( ".detail-container" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      $(".ui-dialog-content").empty();
      var dateHTML="<p> Date : "+$(this).data("date")+"</p>";//get the data-date attribute of the element and store it as html element to append
      var uidHTML="<p> User ID : "+$(this).data("uid")+"</p>";//get the userID
      var titleHTML="<p> Title : "+$(this).find('p').text()+" </p>";
      var finalHTML=dateHTML + uidHTML + titleHTML;
      $(".ui-dialog-content").append(finalHTML);
});
```

> **The above flow can still be optimized but just to make you understand**
>   **I've made it part by part!**

Comment: Almost there. I also need to append the hidden field text and other data that is not displayed in the "dialog-opener" but is contained in the viewData["Records"] e.g. @item.Date is not displayed but i need it to be shown up in the dialog. Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: @ElizabethDimova updated the answer!! Check and let me know!!